# Randomly order the results of a for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

I've got 108,002 items that I am keeping track of.

55011 of them are going to be given the name "item1"

32531 of them are going to be given the name "item2"

8060 of them are going to be given the name "item3"

12400 of them are going to be given the name "item4"

I'm using a for loop to do this.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 108002; $i++) {


if($i <= 55011){

$item = "item1";

}else if($i > 55011 && $i < 87542 ){

$item = "item2";

}else if($i > 87542 && $i < 95602 ){

$item = "item3";

}else if($i > 95602 && $i <= 108002 ){

$item = "item4";

}

}
```

And then I insert each one into a MySQL database.

But the trick is I want them to be inserted in a random order so I don't have the first 55,011 items all with the same name etc.

Any ideas how I can do this but still allow for the exact amount of each item?

Comment: Can I ask why on earth you're doing this?

Comment: He He. I need a table in my DB with these records in them to keep track of an inventory of items. I'm only running it once to get the data into the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them into an array and [`shuffle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it.

Comment: @tereško for a one-off task? Sure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're doing this only once, or at least infrequently, in which case you'll probably just want to make a huge array in php and shuffle() it as Amber said.

If that array would be too big/slow you could do something like this (untested pseudo-code)

```
left = [0, 55011, 32531, 8060, 12400]
for i in 108001..0
    r = rnd_zero_to_one_less_than(i)
    for j in 1..4
        if r < left[j]
            left[j] -= 1
            insert("item"+j)
            break
        r -= left[j]
```

That make sense?

Edit: instead of having an array with all the values, you just have "left" which says how many there are left of the 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s. Instead of removing an element at random from the huge array, you can just decrement one of the counts in "left".

Edit: added last two lines of code (how'd I forget those?)

Comment: Yes I'm only doing it once to get the data into the Database.